Rotation invariant svg patterns
The patternUnits property of svg patterns seems to allow defining which coordinate space to use for pattern positions. "userSpaceOnUse" will use the global coordinate system for the pattern position.
I am looking for a similar property for rotation. I want all objects filled with the pattern hash to be rotated by 45° globally. In the standard implementation the rotation of the pattern is also affected.
Here is an example where it does not work:


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="hashPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 10" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />
    </pattern>

    <g id="yourShape">
      <ellipse cx="25" cy="25" rx="15" ry="25" stroke="black" fill="url(#hashPattern)" />
    </g>
  </defs>

  <use href="#yourShape" x="20" y="20" />
  <use href="#yourShape" x="100" y="20" transform="rotate(45 125 45)" />
  <use href="#yourShape" x="20" y="100" transform="rotate(90 45 125)" />
  <use href="#yourShape" x="100" y="100" transform="rotate(180 125 125)" />
</svg>



Instead of the red lines showing into different directions I need all of the lines to show into the same correction.

You want the diagonal hash pattern to run top-left down to bottom-right for any rotation?

Patterns are applied before transforms, so you can't use patterns to get this result. But filters are applied after transforms, so you can use a filter to apply the pattern and you'll get the result you want.

draw the shapes you want individually i.e. don't use use and don't use a transform at all.

Patterns are relative to the shape, so they will rotate with the shape.
The best you can do is duplicate the <pattern> and apply a patternTransform and link that up to each shape. I changed the stroke for each pattern so they are easier to distinguish.
Note: If you add a definition for a hash path shape, you can reference it with use in the duplicated patterns.


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <!-- Actual pattern "shape" -->
    <g id="hashPath">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 10" stroke-width="2" />
    </g>

    <!-- Create various patterns that reference the shape above and rotate -->
    <pattern id="hashPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
      <use href="#hashPath" stroke="red" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="hashPattern-45" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10" patternTransform="rotate(-45)">
      <use href="#hashPath" stroke="blue" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="hashPattern-90" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10" patternTransform="rotate(-90)">
      <use href="#hashPath" stroke="green" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="hashPattern-180" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10" patternTransform="rotate(-180)">
      <use href="#hashPath" stroke="fuchsia" />
    </pattern>

    <g id="yourShape">
      <ellipse cx="25" cy="25" rx="15" ry="25" stroke="black" />
    </g>
  </defs>

  <!-- Apply the approiate rotated pattern for each rotation -->
  <use href="#yourShape" x="20" y="20" fill="url(#hashPattern)"/>
  <use href="#yourShape" x="100" y="20" transform="rotate(45 125 45)" fill="url(#hashPattern-45)" />
  <use href="#yourShape" x="20" y="100" transform="rotate(90 45 125)" fill="url(#hashPattern-90)" />
  <use href="#yourShape" x="100" y="100" transform="rotate(180 125 125)" fill="url(#hashPattern-180)" />
</svg>



As herrstrietzel, mentioned in the comments below, you could create <pattern> definitions that reference a base pattern using href, similar to <use> elements.
The caveat being that the reference pattern is baked into each rotated copy. You no longer have control of the attributes of the pattern shape like in the version above.


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="hashPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 10" stroke-width="2" stroke="red" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern href="#hashPattern" id="hashPattern-45" patternTransform="rotate(-45)" />
    <pattern href="#hashPattern" id="hashPattern-90" patternTransform="rotate(-90)" />
    <pattern href="#hashPattern" id="hashPattern-180" patternTransform="rotate(-180)" />

    <g id="yourShape">
      <ellipse cx="25" cy="25" rx="15" ry="25" stroke="black" />
    </g>
  </defs>

  <use href="#yourShape" x="20" y="20" fill="url(#hashPattern)" />
  <use href="#yourShape" x="100" y="20" transform="rotate(45 125 45)" fill="url(#hashPattern-45)" />
  <use href="#yourShape" x="20" y="100" transform="rotate(90 45 125)" fill="url(#hashPattern-90)" />
  <use href="#yourShape" x="100" y="100" transform="rotate(180 125 125)" fill="url(#hashPattern-180)" />
</svg>




Worth noting: you can also create child patterns by adding a href reference (similar to <use>  elements. See codepen example. Albeit we won't be able to change stroke colors for each element.

@herrstrietzel I noticed that, which is why I elected to have unique patterns that control their own stroke and reference a shared path. I only added color to distinguish each shape for the demonstration. Your solution is reasonable, because the original question was not trying to adjust the stroke color.

I had a similar problem with the scale as well. This solution also works with rescaling the pattern.

You can split it up, so that the pattern is used on a rectangle that has a mask with your ellipses what has a white fill, and then draw the ellipses with the black stroke on top of that.


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="hashPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 10" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />
    </pattern>

    <g id="yourShape">
      <ellipse cx="25" cy="25" rx="15" ry="25" />
    </g>
    
    <g id="yourShapes">
      <use href="#yourShape" x="20" y="20" />
      <use href="#yourShape" x="100" y="20" transform="rotate(45 125 45)" />
      <use href="#yourShape" x="20" y="100" transform="rotate(90 45 125)" />
      <use href="#yourShape" x="100" y="100" transform="rotate(180 125 125)" />
    </g>
    
    <mask id="mask1">
      <use href="#yourShapes" fill="white" stroke="none" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#hashPattern)" mask="url(#mask1)" />
  <use href="#yourShapes" fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>




this is an interesting solution but it would cause me problems if I have to reorganize all of my use elements into the defs. Therefore, I like the accepted solution more.
